# How can I justify not giving my villain the Wish spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, encounter-design, wish, villain

Basically, I have a wizard as a villain who is ambitious, powerful, and has access to nearly unlimited resources. How can I justify giving him any ninth-level spell but not giving him Wish?

Or, alternately, should I just give him Wish, and if so, how do I keep that under control?

A few details that are specific to my case - He's an illusion wizard, he's one of the primary antagonists but almost certainly won't be the final boss, and he's fairly active in the story, showing up to antagonize the players a la Strahd.

The fact that he isn't designed as a final boss character is a big part of what gives me pause re: giving him Wish, but in terms of flavor I'm really struggling to come up with a reason why he wouldn't have that spell.

Comment: Is your concern that Wish is too powerful, or is there some other reason you don't want him to have it?

Comment: Yes, my main concern is that it's too powerful/flexible and could theoretically be used to counteract or reverse almost every plan the players come up with

Comment: @ctenochaetus I mean, the same is true for the *Wish* spell the players presumably  have at that point, no?  Is there a reason that isn't equally unbalanced?  I think we need more information about how you are handling wishes in your campaign, beyond just this one NPC.

Comment: The players are much lower level than the villain at this point, and I'm not sure if the module will take them all the way to 17th level. Plus, this guy has a lot more going for him than ~18th level in wizard as far as combat, so him going "I wish for Foresight" is way more dramatic than it would be on a player anyway

Comment: Don't change the whole question into another question.  Only edit to improve a question.  It invalidates all answers.  Instead, if you need to, ask another question.  Moreover, questions have a history so Edit tags aren't needed.

Comment: I've rolled back the question as to not invalidate the answers. For those who have answered, please remember that we aren't here to generate ideas. If you've got ideas, please [back them up](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3204/how-do-we-ask-and-answer-subjective-questions). **We shouldn't upvote idea generation.**

Comment: I asked this question in the interest of drawing from the experience of those who have confronted a similar problem. The question is on-topic and has already generated at least one meaningful answer. I struggle to understand how this question is too subjective when it concerns a game's built-in feature which is designed to be subjective. Further, my effort to change the question to induce more meaningful/relevant discussion is stymied instead of built upon. Would creating a new question be embraced or be met with the same reaction?

Comment: I also confess myself utterly confused as to why my appreciation of answers and answerers is repulsive enough to merit specific deletion. Who benefits from this? Not the answerers, not the moderators, and certainly not any other third parties. No standards of professionalism advocate for an absence of gratitude - in fact, many hold the opposite position.

Comment: Generally, changing the meaning of a question after answers have been written and voted on is bad, because it's likely to invalidate existing answers and their votes.  Comments are intended for clarification, not gratitude, so things like "good job" are very likely to be deleted, and possibly sooner rather than later.

Comment: Is Wish a Universal spell in 5e?   Can it be in a forbidden school?  Its been a while since I've browsed the spells.

Comment: @NautArch I don't get it. The question is closed for attracting unsupported opinions as answers, but it can't be edited in a way that would invalidate the answers? Aren't they invalid already, if they're unsupported opinions?

Comment: @MarkWells It may be worth opening up a Meta question about that. The problem again lies in people not answering appropriately, but then we have our rule about making fundamental changes after answers come in. As J.A. Streich had said, it's probably best to ask the newer (better) question separately.

Comment: @MarkWells: People shouldn't have answered a primarily opinion-based question to begin with... But OP's edit seems to not have been motivated by that but rather by an intent to ask a new question given a different premise. As such, OP is welcome to ask that new question separately. I do think the new one of "How can a villain with *wish* be kept in check?" is more answerable, at least given the necessary info/parameters.

Comment: @MarkWells I think you bring up a very good point. I do think, in this case that OP would benefit themselves from making it a new question (less cleanup and baggage from this one), but fundamentally changing the question in order to fix an issue I personally think can be acceptable even after answers come in. It's very situational and generally we play it case-by-case. I don't think we have any guidance that sufficiently covers this. A meta might not be amiss and might help to clarify the issue for everyone if you were so inclined to write one.

Comment: @NautArch It is probably worth considering that this view does not seem to be represented by the most recent meta on this issue: ([What kind of edits are acceptable to a question after an answer has been posted?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9094/28591)) We don't seem to have a hardline policy against editing the question after answers come in, it is very much a case-by-case thing.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I did not realize! Do you think we should bring back the edit?

Comment: I think that this is an easy answerable question within the rules of the spell itself, as the most upvoted answer shows.

Comment: @Eddymage But this is also framed is an idea generating question, as every other answer shows. Voting to close as opinion based.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov But the answer is direct and does not need any particular idea: it is just apply the rule, and in this case even if it is (loosely) framed as an idea generating question, I think that it should be remain open.

Answer (score 29):

He does have [Wish](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish), but maybe one of the following either has happened or will happen:

1. He's cast it once, but now he's unable to ever cast it again. From the spell's description:

> Finally, there is a 33 percent chance that you are unable to cast wish
>   ever again.

2. The spells fails, anytime he casts it.

> The GM has great latitude in ruling what occurs in such an instance;
>   the greater the wish, the greater the likelihood that something goes
>   wrong. This spell might simply fail, the effect you desire might only
>   be partly achieved, or you might suffer some unforeseen consequence as
>   a result of how you worded the wish

Comment: What's cool about option 1, for GM purposes, is that it gives the villain a motive to do any arbitrarily crazy thing in a bid to get his *phenomenal cosmic power* back.

Comment: Option 1 has Wish solve the issue itself using an important and unique feature of Wish, and creates a little backstory to boot. Hard to ask for more than that.

Answer (score 3):

### The villain might have never discovered a source to learn it from.

Lore-wise, the knowledge how to cast specific spells doesn't come naturally to wizards. They have to learn their spells from ancient tomes and scrolls, other wizards, meticulous study and experimentation or some other source.

Mechanically, this research process is partially abstracted away for PC wizards, because each time they level up they can just pick two new spells they just suddenly know. I know that inferring designer intent is frowned upon in this community, but I would *guess* this has the purpose to not have every campaign focus on finding new spells for the wizard while still making sure PC wizards get a reasonable arsenal of spells that's appropriate for their character level and fits with the player's vision for their character. It is just assumed that the PC wizard did their studying and research during their off-time throughout the campaign.

But that's not something that necessarily has to apply to NPC wizards as well.

The knowledge to cast an immensely powerful spell like Wish - just like any other 9th level spell - is not something you just stumble upon in a public library. Arcane knowledge of that power-level is usually a well-protected secret held by only a very selected few. Even its very existence might be considered a myth (just because something is in the PHB doesn't mean it's common in-character knowledge in your campaign world). Especially among wizards who specialize in a different school like Illusion, and thus might not be all that well-informed about what is and isn't possible on the cutting edge of Conjuration magic. Yes, I know, that's a worldbuilding detail that's not adequately represented by the spell learning rules for player-characters, which state that learning a spell from a different school is merely twice as hard as learning one from ones chosen arcane tradition. But again, NPCs are not PCs. They do not need to follow the same character building rules.

So it's not implausible that an NPC wizard just never found a source to learn it from, even with "nearly unlimited" resources.

Answer (score 2):

### NPCs can use different rules than PCs in 5e

It is true that in 5e, a PC wizard can pick 2 spells each time they gain a level from the overall wizard spell list, so once they get to 9th level, there is no stopping them from picking wish. However, NPCs do not need to follow the same rules as PCs when being built. The *DMG* says under **Designing NPCs** (p. 92):

> When you give an NPC game statistics, you have three main options: giving the NPC only the few statistics it needs, give the NPC a monster stat block, or give the NPC a class and levels.

So technically, you can design that NPC without elaborating how they got their spells. Why does the [Lich](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/16943-lich) not have Wish as its level 9 spell? Why does the [Archmage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/16789-archmage) not have Wish as their level 9 spell? Both of them can cast level 9 spells, both of them are official monsters, and the Archmage is without doubt the monster-stat-block version of a high-level NPC wizard. You can easily point to precendent, we don't ask for a justification for those, either.

NPCs are build with story and personality in mind first, and with min-maxing, *maybe* second. As are many PCs -- not everyone is a min-maxer.

#### Wish is not the only viable option

A second aspect is that your question implicitly assumes that *wish* is the best of all the level 9 spells by such a wide margin that there is no competition as to what to pick -- you would always pick it. That both assumes that the wizard is purely about maximizing power, rather than pursuing his interests, and that wish in fact is the best when it comes to power.

And while I agree that Wish is a great spell, and probably the overall best and most versatile level 9 spell for wizards, there are other great spell options on level 9. These options do not run the risk of losing them forever when you use them to achieve an effect you cannot get from a level 8 spell. They are entirely defensible picks, even for a PC wizard. *Foresight* might beat it for sheer everyday effectiveness. *True Polymorph* can create all kinds of shenaningans by getting around creature type restrictions of other spells. *Meteor Swarm* is the king of big area damage.

And if you allow for the wizard having chosen their spells following their interest, for an illusion wizard, *Weird* (probably the most sucky of all the options) is a pick from their dedicated School of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few options

#### 1. Consider giving him Wish

Given your comment clarification being concern about the power of Wish, I'd suggest that there are ways to give a character Wish (as would fit with their ambition) without it being overpowered. Given that it's primary function is flexible spell choice once a day, and all other uses risk losing it permanently, it seems reasonable that someone craving power wouldn't want to incur that risk. At a once a day use against an entire party does add an extra punch, it's by no means encounter breaking.

#### 2. Give him something important to have used his Wish on already

Have him burn through his Wish for the day prior to encountering the party. Perhaps something to tie into his villainous backstory.

#### 3. Give him a strong motivation to take a different spell

Perhaps he loves the power to just declare someone dead with a word (Power Word Kill), or has a need to use Gate on a regular basis, or True Polymorph, or Astral Project. Similar to #2, can tie well into a backstory.

#### 4. Don't give him any level 9 spells

He's powerful and ambitious, so perhaps he's still working his way up. You didn't say what level your party is, but if the Wizard needs to be 17 or higher to be a challenge, having Wish probably isn't a big problem for them.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate Wish from access by mortals -- that is, limit it only to very powerful beings, traditionally djinni, angels, and so forth.  Obviously, this must apply to PCs as well as your NPC evil wizard.

If anyone wants to make a Wish, they'll have to find a being that can grant it, and convince them it's a good idea to do so -- likely not so simple, especially for those beings who might be inclined not to seek the least little loophole for an opportunity to thwart the seeker.

This will require altering some magic items, obviously, but that's not a terrible task, compared to keeping a campaign viable when the BBG can just wish away his problems (in the form of the player characters).

Answer (score -4):

Wizards are very egocentric, snooty, and eccentric characters. Maybe he feels that the Wish spell is beneath him and not worth his attention, or maybe he'd prefer to prevail using the spells he's honed and learned over his wizarding career? Plenty of reasons why he wouldn't use the Wish spell that go around the actual mechanics/mechanisms of the spell itself.